# How to allow users to submit a get request to a class View and order item?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

```
<form action="">
    Sort By:
    <select name="ordering">
        <option value="price">Price:Highest to Lowest</option>
        <option value="-price">Price:Lowest to Highest</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
<form>
```

trying to submit these values in a get request.
Tried doing a get_ordering function on a class List View:

```
class GarageListView(ListView):
    model = Vehicles
    template_name = 'garage/garage.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-price']


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['filter'] = VehicleFilter(
            self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context


    def get_ordering(self):
            self.ordering = self.request.GET.get('ordering','-price')
            return self.ordering
```

When users select and submit any sort option, it should refresh the page and sort by value

Comment: What is `VehicleFilter`? Is it a FilterSet from django-filter?

Comment: Ignore that part, it does something else. sorry. But yes it is

Comment: Does your `get_ordering` method not do what it is supposed to? Please show the part of your template where you loop over the `Vehicles`.

Comment: It doesnt. {% for v in filter.qs %}..{%endfor%} was used, which is from the VehicleFilter()

Comment: Please show `VehicleFilter` in that case.

Comment: class VehicleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
    release__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='year', lookup_expr='gte')
    release__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='year', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicles
        fields = ['make', 'brand',
                  'transmission', 'fuelType', 'bodyType']

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230967/discussion-between-firmciti-inc-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using django-filter you should use the [OrderingFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter) to allow the user to select an order:

```py
class VehicleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name="price", lookup_expr='gte')
    max_price = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
    release__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='year', lookup_expr='gte')
    release__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='year', lookup_expr='lte')
    
    o = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        # tuple-mapping retains order
        choices = (
            ('price', 'Price:Highest to Lowest'),
            ('-price', 'Price:Lowest to Highest'),
        ),
        fields={
            'price': 'price',
        },
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Vehicles
        fields = ['make', 'brand',
                  'transmission', 'fuelType', 'bodyType']
```

> **Note**: Your indication for "Highest to Lowest" and "Lowest to Highest" appears wrong? For `-price` it should be "Highest to Lowest"
> etc.

Next since you are using django-filter instead of using `ListView` simply use the [`FilterView`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration) provided by django-filter. This inherits from `MultipleObjectMixin` (which is what `ListView` also inherits from) and hence supports all of the features `ListView` does (pagination , etc.):

```py
from django_filters.views import FilterView


class GarageListView(FilterView):
    model = Vehicles
    filterset_class = VehicleFilter
    template_name = 'garage/garage.html'
    context_object_name = 'cars'
    ordering = ['-price']
```

Now you can simply remove the form you previously had for ordering, the ordering field would show up with the filters form. Also instead of looping over `filter.qs` you should now loop over `object_list` or as per your `context_object_name` it would be `cars`: `{% for v in cars %}..{%endfor%}`

Comment: thanks it worded! however, is there a way to split up the filter-sort form on the template end? say i want one form filtering, then another form at a different place on the page, doing the ordering?

Comment: @FirmCitiInc that is a bit counter-intuitive. Suppose you use the view along with pagination. What happens then is that you have two different forms and when you submit one you lose the others GET parameters (Not to mention you need to make page links too while keeping the current GET parameters). Then you would have to do things like copy the other form and keep it's fields hidden in this form or intercept form submission by javascript, etc to solve this new issue.